# Computer Assigning DHCP IP Addresses on Switch

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, switch

I have four computers on my network, and an Xbox 360, all of which plug into my Comcast router in the following fashion:

Comcast plugs into the router box. Port three of the router goes to a small web server I have running, and port two runs to the family computer. Port one runs to an Ethernet switch upstairs which supplies Internet to an IBM Thinkcentre, the Xbox, and a custom build known internally as "X".

The problem lies in X, as when it is inserted into the network on the switch, it essentially assigns the IP addresses for the IBM and the Xbox. When its off, they lose network status completely and when then `ipconfig /release ipconfig /renew` commands are run on the IBM, it returns a self-assigned IP address.

My question, in short, is what I should do to allow the other computers on the switch, and Xbox respectively, to have Internet when X is turned off. I tried setting static IPs for X and the IBM, but that didn't do anything.

```
Router
-Family Computer - 10.0.0.3
-Dell Web Server - 10.0.0.5
-Ethernet Switch
|-IBM Thinkcetre - 10.0.0.103
|-Xbox 360       - 10.0.0.7
|-X              - 10.0.0.101
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like X is running a DHCP server/service.  You need to stop this DHCP service from running on this box (either that or stop it running from the router).  If you are unsure if this is the case, you can turn off the router and reboot (or renew the lease) on the Family Computer and see if it is assigned an address by the DHCP Server - I'm guessing it will assign an IP address >= 10.0.0.104.

Comment: X is only assigning IP addresses on the switch-level though. Everything connected directly into the router is fine.

Comment: Something doesn't make sense to me.  What IP ranges are set for  each of the DHCP servers to hand out (or why does the X Box get 10.0.0.7).  Also, can you confirm that the ports on the router (excluding the WAN side) are interchangeable, ie that its a generic router rather then something with more smarts - I'm in a different country so I'm making [reasonable] assumptions about the Comcast router)

Comment: It's pretty generic. The DHCP range is 10.0.0.2-100 and there are a few WiFi enabled devices I didn't list.

Comment: The question is what is the DHCP range given from X (I'm guessing it will be 100+) and why does the XBox have an IP of 10.0.0.7 when other devices on that switch have in IP greater then 10.0.0.100

Comment: I don't know. It's not set up for DHCP at all. The Xbox is 10.0.0.7 because there are WiFi devices that connect the router; I only listed wired devices.